# Only degrees when using buffer tool?

Tags: qgis

I am puzzled. For what ever reason I was able to buffer choosing metres for distance the other day, now I am not. I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Anyone with any ideas?

[image]

Do not know what to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layer's coordinate system is The World Geodetic System (WGS84). That's why meter unit is not suggested in that system. If you work with projected coordinates, you will get 'meter' available.